# How to install Firebase SDKs with CocoaPods

Tags: ruby, xcode, rubygems, cocoapods, sudo

I've been trying to add Firebase SDKs to my iOS application.

I ran

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

to then run `pod init` in my project directly but I keep getting an error of

```
sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/gem`: No such file or directory error.
```

If I run `ruby - v`, I get an error

```
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Have you looked in `/usr/local/bin` to confirm that neither `ruby` nor `gem` are there? And if they're not there, it's time to check why your environment is pointing to that location rather than to the system install in `/usr/bin`.  Did you set up aliases pointing to a non-system install in `/usr/local/bin`, and later delete the local installation?

Comment: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; restart your shell; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.7`. [Don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/). (and don't use `sudo` if you're using RVM)

Comment: Don't use `sudo` unless you intend to modify the Ruby installed by Apple, which is usually NOT what you really want. RVM or rbenv are excellent tools to manage a user-modifiable Ruby in your home directory. rbenv is less intrusive but both work well.

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"
and "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)".
 Run `gem env` and add the output to your question by copying/pasting the result into your text, formatting it appropriately. Don't use "edit" or "update" tags as we can see what changed when if we want to.

Comment: "`ruby - v`"? The command is `ruby -v`, no space between `-` and `v`.

Comment: @anothermh this worked! thank you so much